# Pull dna sequence by feature from genbank file

Tags: python-2.7, biopython

I have genbank files consisting up multiple annotated contigs. What I'd like to do is separate that out into a database that has individual gene records containing each 'CDS' feature, along with its dna and amino acid sequence. So far this works just fine:

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(open_file, 'gb'):
   for feature in record.features:
        if feature.type == 'CDS':
            gene_record = {
                'locus_tag':feature.qualifiers['locus_tag'][0],
                'translation':feature.qualifiers['translation'][0],
                }
```

The trouble I'm having is getting the dna sequence. The genbank file is formatted thus:

```
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..29869
                     /organism="Arthrobacter"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /strain="strain_name"
     gene            complement(4..462)
                     /locus_tag="ArthroDRAFT_00001"
     CDS             complement(4..462)
                     /locus_tag="ArthroDRAFT_00001"
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /translation="LSTGKELLNYQSALNDIHDEFSRAQQSDAGVSHLSVAKITEKLS
                     YLKATALQMDDLFSVLRKQGVSLRSTGLADWASVPTIQDDKEEGKTEPSLAKKEISSR
                     TTSKPNKIDFPKFEYPDHGQPTNKIRVGTILDTFSESAFSYEWINVALQD"
     gene            complement(1126..1842)
                     /locus_tag="ArthroDRAFT_00002"
     CDS             complement(1126..1842)
                     /locus_tag="ArthroDRAFT_00002"
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /translation="VPRAFIYGSCVGGDTANVFPSDWDRPTYVARQSIISAAFGPTSV
                     EGDIELTSAFQRSMLEGDIEATAFPRLRQELPTHDVLILDIVDERLGVYELAPGKYLT
                     RSMELISSKLIGKQPVTPRLIEFGSDEHYGLWTRSVDMLVDVVKHGGIPVFALLPPWS
                     EKSIQGEDLTWHSVSVDLMNNKYARYNEYLVQSEFTVVTVPDEEALGDAEHKWGLAPF
                     HYTESVYESLRDQILVGVSS"
...etc

ORIGIN
        1 ccctcaatcc tgaagagcca cattgatcca ttcgtatgag aatgcagatt ccgagaatgt
       61 atcaagaatt gttcctacac gtattttgtt tgtcggctgg ccgtggtccg gatactcaaa
      121 ttttggaaag tcaatcttgt ...
```

So, I have the location for each feature, but I need to somehow parse the dna sequence to pull the right dna sequence, and I'm sort of at a loss for how to do this. `feature.location` gives me what seems like a useful output:

```
[3:462](-)
[1125:1842](-)
[2159:3755](-)
[5190:5532](-)
[6226:6493](+)
```

But the only way I know to use this would be to parse that with regular expressions, then do `record.seq[start_num:finish_num]`. And then if it's on the - strand, run whatever that is through `reverse_complement`.

This seems way too convoluted, and I thought biopython must have a more efficient way, but I can't seem to find it. I noticed that the `feature.location` already seems to have 1 subtracted from it to account for python's 0 index, so that number must be useable... right?

EDIT: the `SeqFeature.location` seems like it's what I want to use, but can't figure out how: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqFeature.FeatureLocation-class.html

EDIT2: Looks like I can do

`record.seq[feature.location.start:feature.location.end]`

This does not yet work for negative strand stuff though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an "extract" method of location object.

```
dna_seq = feature.location.extract(record)
```

This works fine.

Comment: I found this a couple of months later... forgot to come back and answer this - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, never mind - more googling and experimentation got me to a better solution. Not sure if it's the best solution, I'll leave the question up and unanswered in case anyone has better ideas. What I did to get the DNA sequence is the following:

```
if feature.location.strand == 1:
    dna_seq = record.seq[
        feature.location.start:feature.location.end
    ]
elif feature.location.strand == -1:
    dna_seq = record.seq[
        feature.location.start:feature.location.end
    ].reverse_complement()
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it seems to work...